# Xamarin "xcodebuild output not as expected"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, calabash, xamarin.uitest

I'm trying to get Xamarin.UITests working for an iOS project and I keep getting this error:

`SetUp : Calabash.XDB.Core.Exceptions.ExternalProcessException : xcodebuild output not as expected`

If anybody has any idea how to continue debugging this, please let me know.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For those struggling with the same issue: My problem was that XCode tools could not be located. How to fix:

1. Open XCode > Preferences > Location > XCodeTools
2. Select XCode from the "Command Line Tools" drop down.
   [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3E68C.png)

Comment: It's very odd, because I knew about the "Command Line Tools" setting and had previously set it properly, but when I checked this based on your answer, the setting was blank until I put it properly on Xcode 9.2. So I think something must have deactivated the setting somehow, though I'm not sure what could have impacted that.

Comment: This is more of an anecdote, but I'm curious if it happens to anybody else. I recently installed [HomeBrew](https://brew.sh) and then was hit by the above error. I know HomeBrew uses the Xcode Command Line Tools, and I wonder if the HomeBrew install was the reason my Xcode preferences changed?

Comment: @BrandonMinnick I had the exact same issue so I'm assuming HomeBrew changed the setting.